# terraform plan works one way but not the other?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Terraform v0.12.17

I just have 2 simple files

```
snapshot_id.tf = gets a list of my completed EBS volume snapshot ids
data "aws_ebs_snapshot_ids" "jenkins_master" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["jenkins-master"]
  }
  filter {
    name   = "status"
    values = ["completed"]
  }
}

ebs_volume_green.tf = use above data resource to create an EBS volume
resource "aws_ebs_volume" "jenkins_master_ebs_green" {
  availability_zone = var.availability_zones.green
  snapshot_id = data.aws_ebs_snapshot_ids.jenkins_master.id
         size = data.aws_ebs_snapshot_ids.jenkins_master.volume_size
         type = "gp2"
  tags = {
    Name = "jenkins-master-green"
    Environment = "sandbox"
    Product = "Jenkins"
    Role = "master"
  }
}
```

This passes, so obviously the resource has `volume_size` defined.

```
$ terraform plan -target ebs_volume_green.tf -out out.output
$ terraform apply out.output
```

But this fails, i.e., if I don't specify the `-target` option. Why?

```
$ terraform plan -out out.output    
Error: Unsupported attribute

  on ebs_volume_green.tf line 4, in resource "aws_ebs_volume" "jenkins_master_ebs_green":
   4:          size = data.aws_ebs_snapshot_ids.jenkins_master.volume_size

This object has no argument, nested block, or exported attribute named
"volume_size".
```

Comment: You can't target a file like that so it's not clear what you're doing here that you seem to have obfuscated to create an example. You can only target a specific resource etc. Can you make sure that your question contains a properly reproducible example please?

Comment: You also seem to be confusing `aws_ebs_snapshot_ids` with `aws_ebs_snapshot`. These are different data sources. If you use `aws_ebs_snapshot` then you should have the `volume_size` output that you expect. The plural data source instead just returns the IDs that you can then iterate through with the `aws_ebs_snapshot` data source to get the `volume_size` later.

Comment: Ok I updated my example with a real resource for a target.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR please post your second comment as THE answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have confused the [`aws_ebs_snapshot_ids`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/ebs_snapshot_ids) and the [`aws_ebs_snapshot`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/ebs_snapshot) data sources.

You should only be using the plural data sources if you need to return multiple of something. You can then pass these IDs into the individual data source that returns more useful information or just pass the IDs into something that takes a list of IDs such as the `aws_autoscaling_group` resource's `vpc_zone_identifier` parameter.

In your case if you just want the most recent snapshot that matches your tags you would just use the following:

```
data "aws_ebs_snapshot" "jenkins_master" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["jenkins-master"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "status"
    values = ["completed"]
  }
}
```

This will then have the [`volume_size` attribute](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/ebs_snapshot#volume_size) from the data source that you are expecting.

In your question you can see that it plans and applies successfully when you target just the data source but it's only when your plan includes a usage of a resource or data source's output that doesn't exist that Terraform will complain because it's not evaluating everything in `-target` mode. In general if you have to use `-target` then something is wrong somewhere and you should see that as a red flag.